# Angular Material Autocomplete: Autocomplete Panel doesn't collapse on Page Scroll when there are more than one Autocomplete control

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular7, mat-autocomplete

As shown in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmarv-xfnjrd), I'm facing issue in closing the Autocomplete controls except first Autocomplete control(City) on Page Scroll when there are multiple Autocomplete Controls as shown in the stackblitz sample.

[image]

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Click on first - **City** Autocomplete control and let it stay expanded.
2. Try to do page level scroll and then the **City** Autocomplete control collapses.
3. Now Click on Second - **State**/**Country** Autocomplete control and let it stay expanded.
4. Try to do page level scroll and see the **State**/**Country** Autocomplete control doesn't collapse.

**Expected Behavior**: State/Country Autocomplete control should collapse similar to City Autocomplete control on Page scroll.

**Actual Behavior**: State/Country Autocomplete control doesn't collapse on Page scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `@ViewChildren` decorator in order to hold of each of `MatAutocompleteTrigger`s:

```
@ViewChildren(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autoCompleteTriggers: QueryList< MatAutocompleteTrigger>;

closePanels() {
  this.autoCompleteTriggers.forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.panelOpen) {
      trigger.closePanel();
    }
  });
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmarv-brpjsp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts)**